# Braintree for iOS apps with paypal integration

Tags: paypal, braintree

Is the a braintree iOS SDK for native iOS app payment system integration that uses paypal payments too?

I cannot seem to find one. Is there a third party sample code?

Or is there a guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, please [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Yes, the [Braintree iOS SDK includes PayPal support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/guides/paypal/overview):

> ## PayPal
>
> Braintree offers a few options when accepting PayPal payments. First,
> you'll need to choose whether you would like to use our [Drop-In UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/sdk/client/drop-in) or
> a [custom integration](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side-configuration).
>
> #### Vault vs. Checkout
>
> Next, you can choose between our [Vault](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/vault) and [Checkout](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal) flows. Below is a
> comparison of the two options:
>
> > - Vault Compatibility: iOS, Android, and web
> > - Checkout Compatibility: Web only

Comment: Thank you, love the fact that you guys provide drop-in UI

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Would you be willing to share more about what you liked/didn't like about it? Email me mickey.reiss@getbraintree.com.

Comment: How to implement braintree with vault in ios? I am using this link https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/vault/ios/v4 but not able to install pod 'Braintree/DataCollector'
pod 'Braintree/PayPalDataCollector'. it is giving ios version error even i have set minumum ios 9.3 then also it is giving error. Can you provide correct link for implement braintree with vault feature in ios and android as well?

Comment: @DJtiwari Here's the [Braintree PayPal documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/ios/v4). You will need to provide more details about your issue. Can you post your Podfile and the error message you're receiving?

Comment: After login into PayPal, it show return to merchant. Why it not showing amount and other info.

Comment: @Rajesh I don't understand your question. Please contact Braintree support and they can help you.

Comment: @agf Is there any demo for Paypal and Apple Pay Drop In UI using Swift 3?

Comment: @Mamta The Braintree docs include snippets for Swift https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/ios/v4

For additional help, it'd be best to contact Braintree support directly: https://articles.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact