# How to Integrate Braintree Paypal with iOS?

Tags: ios

Is the a braintree iOS latest Version SDK for native iOS app payment system integration that uses paypal payments too?

I cannot seem to find a smart Sampleone. Is there a any sample code?

Or is there a smart guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can integrate Braintree and Paypal using the same SDK. Please [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219522/braintree-for-ios-apps-with-paypal-integration) for more details.
Hope this will help you.